# Where can I find Shri Dattatreya Bhujanga Prayata Stotram?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, guru, stotra, dattatreya

I'm searching for Shri Dattatreya Bhujanga Prayata Stotram, probably written by Shri Adi Shankaracharya.

Does any one have it?? Please provide a link to it.